# Updating text on a DIV causes it to update on the previous DIV's already clicked - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to solve this for the last couple of hours but all attempts failed...

What I need to do is to click on a DIV that will cause another DIV to pop up.
Inside the pop up there are some `<li>` and after clicking it, the attribute name is "transferred" to the first DIV clicked.

Ok, I managed to do that but after I update the first DIV and when I try to update the second DIV, the first DIV also gets updated and when I try to update the third DIV the other two gets updated ass well.

Can anyone help me to fix it and only update the DIV it was clicked on leaving the previous as it was supposed to be?

Here is the code:

> HTML

```
<div class="num-1">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/180x180/eeeeee/000000.jpg" width="180" height="180">
  <p class="brand"></p>
  <p class="name"></p>
</div>

<div class="num-2">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/180x180/eeeeee/000000.jpg" width="180" height="180">
  <p class="brand"></p>
  <p class="name"></p>
</div>

<div class="num-3">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/180x180/eeeeee/000000.jpg" width="180" height="180">
  <p class="brand"></p>
  <p class="name"></p>
</div>

<div class="num-4">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/180x180/eeeeee/000000.jpg" width="180" height="180">
  <p class="brand"></p>
  <p class="name"></p>
</div>

<div class="num-5">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/180x180/eeeeee/000000.jpg" width="180" height="180">
  <p class="brand"></p>
  <p class="name"></p>
</div>

<div class="popup">
  <ul>
    <li name="{{PHP GENERATED $name}}">{{PHP GENERATED $name}}</li>
    <li name="{{PHP GENERATED $name}}">{{PHP GENERATED $name}}</li>
    <li name="{{PHP GENERATED $name}}">{{PHP GENERATED $name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> jQuery

```
//Openning the .popup and assigning the names
//First check the number of the div it was clicked on
$('img').on('click', function() {
  var num = $(this).parent().attr('class').match(/\d+/)[0];
  $('.popup').fadeIn();

  //Click li to update the brand and name on the page
  $('.popup li').on('click', function() {

    //Check the name and split it
    var nameComplete = $(this).attr('name');
    var Array = nameComplete.split(" ");

    //Check the first word and identify it as brand, also update on the page
    var brand = Array[0];
    $('.num-' + num + ' .brand').text(brand);

    //Check the rest of the array for the name and update it on the page
    var name = '';
    for(var i=1; i<Array.length ;i++) {
      name = name + Array[i] + ' ';
    }
    name = $.trim(name);

    $('.num-' + num + ' .name').text(name);

    $('.popup').fadeOut();

  });
});
```

Someone might wonder if I'm getting the number of the DIV correctly.
I did `console.log(num);` and it shows that I'm clicking on the correct DIV because the DIV class is `num-X` (X = 1 to 5), 1 for 1, 2 for 2,...

The names of the `<li>` are ok, it works as it should, split it and get the right part to "transfer".

I guess I made the proper modifications to better understanding the code.

Comment: Your selector in `$('.div img').on('click', function() {...` has a point. Is this wanted? Do you really want to point to a class (`.div` or `div`)?

Comment: Sorry I had to adapt it to put it here, I'll update it to `$('img')` only. Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle of this code there are multiple problems with this code and it ll be easier if we have a working js fiddle

Comment: And there is a click function inside another one. [**Here is a fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/chimos/dk62kvhp/), tried to arrange a bit but still don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('img').on('click', function() {
      var num = $(this).parent().attr('class').match(/\d+/)[0];
      window.num = num;
      $('.popup').fadeIn();
    });

    //Click li to update the brand and name on the page
    $('.popup li').on('click', function() {

      //Check the name and split it
      var nameComplete = $(this).attr('name');
      var Array = nameComplete.split(" ");

      //Check the first word and identify it as brand, also update on the page
      var brand = Array[0];
      $('.num-' + window.num + ' .brand').text(brand);

      //Check the rest of the array for the name and update it on the page
      var name = '';
      for(var i=1; i<Array.length ;i++) {
        name = name + Array[i] + ' ';
      }
      name = $.trim(name);

      $('.num-' + num + ' .name').text(name);

      $('.popup').fadeOut();
    });
```

Separate both the click events in separate functions. Probably whats happening in your code is that every time you click on a div a new click event handler is attached to the '.popup li' and every time you click on one of the '.popup li' all the click handlers are activated. Thus explaining the multiple divs being updated.

Second option you have is to use [jquery.off](https://api.jquery.com/off/). This way every time you attach an event handle with .click to the '.popup li' you also remove it after you work is done and complete. Since this would have made your code harder to debug and to read i have preferred the first method in this answer.

NOTE**- i have changed the num to window.num which isnt a very good practice (keeping a global variable) but im sure you will be able to refactor the code once you get it to work

Comment: Sweet as, Parv!! I was trying to get the jsfiddle working and you did the trick! I wasn't able to identify that all handlers were being activated, I thought it had to do something with the target. Thank you so much! I'll check about the `window.num` variable later, now gotta run to meet my girlfriend lol.